# Nginx and Chrome, after 5 request on static content (50MB) Chrome say Pending

Tags: google-chrome, nginx

I have a server with 8 core and 32Gb of memory, I use Nginx and this is my Conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 16;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

events {
        worker_connections 4000;

        use epoll;

        multi_accept on;
}

http {
        open_file_cache          max=200000 inactive=20s;
        open_file_cache_valid    30s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
        open_file_cache_errors   on;

        sendfile on;
        client_max_body_size 2048m;

        tcp_nopush  on;
        tcp_nodelay on;

        keepalive_timeout  15 15;
#       keepalive_requests 100000;

        reset_timedout_connection on;

        client_header_timeout  1m;
        client_body_timeout    1m;
        send_timeout           1m;

        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;

        gzip              on;
        gzip_disable      "msie6";
        gzip_buffers      256 4k;
        gzip_comp_level   5;
#       gzip_http_version 1.0;
        gzip_min_length   1280;
        gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss application/json text/javascript image/x-icon image/bmp;
        gzip_vary         on;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

On my website, when I see 5 movies, after, I have to wait or close and restart my Chrome for view other 5 movies...

In Chrome Network, I can see the URL but with the status: (pending) and nothing other...
I can see on Chrome (in bottom left): **Waiting an available Socket**

Any one have a solution?
Is my nginx.conf good?

Serioulsy, thx in advance

Comment: Does that happen on firefox? Does that happen with an empty cache?
Are you serving the movie as a file (downloadable) or as streaming? What are you using for streaming on client-side?
Best regards.

Comment: yes, the same on firefox and IE, with or without an empty cache.
The movie is served as file (download), I use <video> for the player.

Comment: I suggest you post this question to Nginx English Mailing List forum. Then point this topic to the guy that anwsers your question so he can anwser and get the points. Thats how I get the anwsers I need for more complex nginx problems. Seems faster. I never worked with videos and am not that experienced with nginx so I wont event try to touch your problem. Make sure you set debug log and post debug logs too. That and error logs for anything produced for this specific problem. Best regards and good luck. http://forum.nginx.org/list.php?2